# Compatibility of subfigure with subfig package

Tags: graphics, subcaption, subfig

Suppose, I have the grouping of images as specified below.

My problem is that I want to include this kind of image grouping in an environment that uses the `subfig` package and that `subcaption` and `subfig` do not go well together. My question is therefore: How do I replicate the image grouping below in a `subfig` environment --> e.g.  How do I obtain the same result as you shown below but with the \subfloat macro from subfig package?

The goal really is to have a big image in the middle, and 8 images around it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[]{.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
    \caption{A short figure}

\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[]{.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
    \caption{A short figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad

\begin{subfigure}[]{.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
    \caption{A short figure}

    \vspace{2ex}

    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
    \caption{A short figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{x}
\caption{A tall figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[]{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
\caption{A short figure}

\vspace{2ex}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
\caption{A short figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad

\begin{subfigure}[]{.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
    \caption{A short figure}

\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[]{.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
    \caption{A short figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad

\caption{The full caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! do i understood you correct that you like to obtain the same result as you shown in question, with use of the `\subfloat` macro from `subfig` package?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want - sorry for not having been specific enough.

Comment: If you are interested, I have written a version of \subfloat that uses only the subcaption package.

Comment: Yes, of course I would be interested! Where can I find it? @JohnKormylo

Comment: Actually, the subcaption package already provides \subcaptionbox which is roughly equivalent to \subfloat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see, if the following solution can help you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo,               % demo is just for the example
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{4}{X} @{}}
    & \subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}
        & \subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}
            &                                                           \\
\subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X}{
        \multirow[t]{2}{=}{\subfloat[A tall image]{\includegraphics[height=78mm,valign=t]{x}}}
                                                    }
        & \subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}       \\
\subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}
    &   &   & \subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}   \\
    & \subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}
        & \subfloat[A short image]{\includegraphics[valign=t]{x}}
            &                                                           \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{The full caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes! it absolutely does. Thank you very much. I have just a small add-on question: see below

Comment: I would like to know why the formatting turns out to be slightly different in my environment - see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pscrs.png

Comment: with my code?  if you not change anything the only reason which cross my mind is that your `latex` installation has older packages than mine (i test code with recent `miktex` suite, upgraded yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a version of `\subfloat` which is compatible with subcaption.

Adding `\sufloatbox` is probably overkill, but it is conceivable that `#2` could contain code using, for example, `\box0`.  I noticed that both `\subfloat` and `\caption` use `\@tempboxa`, albeit for different purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox{\subfloatbox}

\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][\empty]% #1 = caption (optional), #2 = image
{\bgroup
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}%
  \savebox\subfloatbox{#2}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\wd\subfloatbox}
    \usebox\subfloatbox
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
      \stepcounter{subfigure}%
    \else
      \caption{#1}%
    \fi
  \end{subfigure}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\noindent\rlap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[\blindtext]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-c}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an even simpler version based on `\subfigurebox`.

```
\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][\empty]{%
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \subcaptionbox*{}{#2}%
    \stepcounter{subfigure}%
  \else
    \subcaptionbox{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}
```

Comment: Since version `2019/08/31 v1.3` the `subcaption` package offers `\subfloat`.