# customize reference to subfloat

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

This script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
See Fig. \ref{fig:exa}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[example a]{
    \label{fig:exa}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }
  \subfloat[example b]{
    \label{fig:exb}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

renders output

[image]

How can I format the reference to subfloat as "Fig. 1(a)".

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer in this very closely related (duplicate) question: [Adding parentheses around subfig references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16291/134144)

Comment: @leandriis - I see there is also a subcapton answer, in case anyone wants to overcome their subfig addiction (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package/481921#481921).