# How to center multiple figures and their descriptions

Tags: spacing, graphics, minipage

I am writing a paper for one of my classes on Catalan numbers.  I have a section where I'm trying to include three different figures that I would like to be centered with their corresponding descriptions centered under them.  I'm not very experienced at Latex and I realize this code is probably a mess, but I use the same method for other figures later in the paper and those line up fine.  I have included a screenshot of what the pdf looks like after I run the Latex document.  As you can see, the figures and their descriptions are all there, but the images are off center and I'm not sure why.  I've tried messing with their scales in case that was the problem but that didn't solve it.  I've also tried it without the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` at the start and end of the code but that didn't work either.  If anyone has any suggestions about how to fix the problem or what the issue is, it would be much appreciated.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}  
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{StaircaseWalk1x1.png}  
\captionof{figure}{1x1 Grid}  
\end{minipage}  
\hspace{1.2cm}  
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}  
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{StaircaseWalk2x2.png}  
\captionof{figure}{2x2 Grid}  
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1.2cm}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}  
\includegraphics[scale=.65]{StaircaseWalk3x3.png}  
\captionof{figure}{3x3 Grid}  
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
```

[image: Figures not aligned properly]

Comment: Just add `\centering` before `\includegraphics`.

Comment: That solved the issue for the first two figures but the third one is still out of line.

Comment: You need to increase the width of the last minipage accordingly *if* you want to stay with what you have, There are simpler options like a tabular, but it is hard to spell this out because no one has your figures (apart from you).

Comment: Changing the width solved the problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You can measure the width of the image using `\subfloat` or a savebox.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package/481921#481921 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow, graphicx, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\floatsetup{style=plain, floatrowsep=qquad, heightadjust=object, valign=c, captionskip=2.5ex}
\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight, labelfont=it, labelsep=endash}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[1.2\FBwidth]{\caption{Leonardo da Vinci: Lady with an Ermine}\label{vinci}}
{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{hermine}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Paolo Uccello: The battle of San Romano}\label{uccello}}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{SanRomano}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you only need to insert `\centering` inside each `minipage` in the first two figures. for third figures you not need `minipage` for enclosing of image:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{StaircaseWalk1x1.png}
\caption{1x1 Grid}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{StaircaseWalk2x2.png}
\caption{2x2 Grid}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.65]{StaircaseWalk3x3.png}
\caption{3x3 Grid}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]