# How to include side-by-side pdf-images into pdfLatex environment (using subfloat)?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, includegraphics

I have to include 10 pdf images within `2*5` or `5*2` size. We have tried using `tabular` and `subfloat` as shown below. 
displayed: MISSING $ INSERTED

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
:
:
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\subfloat[Thumb Flexion]{
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{chapters/3.Methods/Paper1 and general discussion/gfxpaper1/Thumb_Flexion.pdf}}    &
\subfloat[Index Flexion]{
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{chapters/3.Methods/Paper1 and general discussion/gfxpaper1/Index_Flexion.pdf}}        \\
:
:
\end{tabular}
\caption{Finger Configurations}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

kindly help in working code.

Also please suggest other direct alternatives, if any.

Many Thanks

[image: Error in rendering pdf-images in overleaf:pdfLatex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... BTW: Blanks in path and filename is not a very good idea, also the `_` in your filename seems to result in your given error message. Can you omit the complete path (copy the images in the same directory you have the tex code) and change `_` to `-` in the filenames?

Comment: The `subfig` and the `subcaption` environment can not be used in the same document. You should recieve an error message about this.

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package/481921#481921 useful.