# How to adjust spacing between words in caption of sub-figures?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, subfig

I used subfig package to position multiple images within a figure.
As you can see the captions are weirdly spaced. How can I fix the spacing of the captions?
The code I used is the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subfloat[Average Filtering (PSNR=32.8964)]
{\includegraphics[width=2.51cm,height=2.3cm]{Fig7a_Avg_Bab.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=2.1cm, height=2.3cm]{Fig7a_Avg_Pepp.png}}\quad\quad\quad
\subfloat[Gamma Correction(PSNR=26.3691)]
{\includegraphics[width=2.51cm,height=2.3cm]{Fig7b_gamma_bab.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=2.1cm, height=2.3cm]{Fig7b_gamma_pepp.png}}\quad
\subfloat[Cropping(PSNR=21.7852)]
{\includegraphics[width=2.51cm,height=2.3cm]{Fig7c_crop_bab.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=2.1cm, height=2.3cm]{Fig7c_crop_pepp.png}}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Outcome of the code I used]

Comment: The easy solution is to insert `\raggedright` into the caption.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package/481921?r=SearchResults&s=3|27.2193#481921

Comment: The easiest way to do so is adding the option `justification=raggedright` when loading the `subfig` package: `\usepackage[...,justification=raggedright]{subfig}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption, subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize, justification=centering}
%   \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize, justification=raggedright} % if you prefer this style
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=2.5cm,height=2.3cm}
\subfloat[Average Filtering ($\mathrm{PSNR}=32.8964$)  \label{fig:main-a}]
    {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\quad      %Fig7a_Avg_Bab.png
     \includegraphics[width=2.1cm]{example-image}}  %Fig7a_Avg_Pepp.png}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Gamma Correction ($\mathrm{PSNR}=26.3691$)  \label{fig:main-b}]
    {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\quad      %{Fig7b_gamma_bab.png}\quad
     \includegraphics[width=2.1cm]{example-image}}  %{Fig7b_gamma_pepp.png}}

\subfloat[Cropping ($\mathrm{PSNR}=21.7852$)   \label{fig:main-c}]
    {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}           %{Fig7c_crop_bab.png}\quad
     \includegraphics[width=2.1cm]{example-image}}  %{Fig7c_crop_pepp.png}}
\caption{\lipsum[66]}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small. complete document which can be tested as it is. An example MWE is document example above, which beside of solution of your problem gives information about page layout and used packages, which are necessary for solving your problem.
- Some ideas, how to solve your problem, has been already given in coments to your question. Proposed MWE use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{...}` for local settings of subloat captions (by this you can at other `\subfloat`s, which has for example longer caption's text you can use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}`.
- For shorter code for your figure is used keays `Gin`, whre are defined common width and height of images. For images, which you like to have narrower (why?),  the image width is still defined locally.
- Corrected are small glitches in writing of sub-captions
- Added are labels which enables referencing figure as well sub-figures.