# subtable alternative. subfig-subcaption conflict

Tags: subcaption, subfig

I'm currently writing my thesis and I need to list two sets of data I'm taking from literature. Since they're analogous but different (one gives me `$t_0$`, the other gives me `$\sqrt{t_0}$`, this is the difference!) I want to put each set of data in its own table, but I want the two tables next to each other.

I tested the `subtable` environment and it works as I wish but to use it I need the `subcaption` package, which goes into conflict with `subfig`.

Is there another package that allows me to use a subtable-like environment without going into conflict with `subfig`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `subfig` and `subcaption` packages shouldn't both be loaded. You say the `subtable` environment (provided by the `subcaption` package) "works as [you] wish", why not use its machinery for both subtables? Alternatively, why not use the `subfig` package's machinery for both subtables?

Comment: Actually, subcaption also provides a version of `\subfloat` now.  There is no need for the subfig package at all.  (Of mostly historical interest, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package/481921?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C30.6675#481921)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I didn't know that there is a \subfloat version in subcaption!. I started using subfloat from subfig few years ago because the guide I use to learn LaTeX suggested that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mico Yes when I don't load the subfig package the subtable environment works fine but the picture I have already loaded broke, so I wanted to use subfig too. I'm gonna see to fix the various subfloat I already have and remove subfig this time!